# code transformation for mips program

Tags: mips

I was wondering if anyone can help in a simple solution. I have a program in assembly that counts decimals from 0-31 and counts in binary beginning from the 5th left digit. I want to transform the program to count 0-31 in binary and show it in console in normal count starting from the right digit. Here's the first code:

```
main:

    addi $9,$0,27 #example number

    addi $10,$0,5

    addi $2,$0,1

L1:

    and $4,$9,$2

    syscall

    srl $9,$9,1

    addi $10,$10,-1

    nbe $10,$0,L1

    end
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So what is your question ? No one is going to do the whole thing for you, but if you have a specific problem that is preventing you from completing this assignment then please state what it is.

Comment: What is this uncommented code supposed to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: Hint: there's an `srlv` instruction (though there's more than one way of solving this problem).

Comment: Well this code shows in screen a binary number starting '00000' for 0 '10000' for 1 '01000' for 2 ,and it goes until 31.i want to reverse it and  the program will show the exact binary number for 1 '00001' ,2 '00010' until 31 ,using simple instructions like shifting i don't need a completed code for decimal to binary.Just a hint on which logical shift to use  and what logic instructions like 'and' and 'or'. Also i just started with Mips .Thank you Michael i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Just found it:

```
.data 
.text

main:
    addi $9,$0,23
    addi $10,$0,5
    addi $2,$0,1
    sll $8,$2,4  
Loop1:
    and $4,$8,$9
    srl $4,$4,4
    syscall
    sll $9,$9,1  
    addi $10,$0,-1
    bne $10,$0, Loop1
.end main
```